# Scrapy throuws Exception "raise _DefGen_Return(val) twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: "

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, twisted, twisted.internet, scrapinghub

When I run the code locally (windows 10) everything works fine.
Have checked other answers here and other resources, but failed to figure out any solution. 
After deploying to ScrapingHub Im getting this error message:

```
[scrapy.core.scraper] Spider error processing <POST http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/new_sch.asp> (referer: http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/) Less
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1276, in returnValue
    raise _DefGen_Return(val)
twisted.internet.defer._DefGen_Return: <200 http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/new_sch.asp>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 42, in process_spider_input
    result = method(response=response, spider=spider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy_pagestorage.py", line 68, in process_spider_input
    self.save_response(response, spider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy_pagestorage.py", line 102, in save_response
    self._writer.write(payload)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapinghub/hubstorage/batchuploader.py", line 224, in write
    data = jsonencode(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapinghub/hubstorage/serialization.py", line 38, in jsonencode
    return dumps(o, default=jsondefault)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

Here is a snippet of my Scrapy function that throws this error
The `ToDate` and `FromDate` are passed as arguments to spider:

```
start_urls = ['http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/']
def parse(self, response):
        # inspect_response(response, self)

        url = 'http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us/or_web1/new_sch.asp'
        headers = {
                        'upgrade-insecure-requests': "1",
                        'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36",
                        'origin': "http://oris.co.palm-beach.fl.us",
                        'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        'dnt': "1",
                        'accept': "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3",
                        'cache-control': "no-cache",
                                                }
        # Date range should be visin 90 days
        data = {'FromDate': self.FromDate,
                     'PageSize': '500',
                     'RecSetSize': '500',
                     'ToDate': self.ToDate,
                     'consideration': '',
                     'search_by': 'DocType',
                     'search_entry': 'LP'}                                            
        body = urlencode(data)                                         
        yield scrapy.Request(url, method="POST", headers = headers, body = body,  callback = self.parsed)

def parsed(self, response):
        # inspect_response(response, self)
        # Getting all View urls.
        urls=response.xpath("//a[@class = 'list_2']/@href").extract()
        for url in urls:
            url = url.replace('\r', '').replace('\t','').replace('\n','')
            url = url.replace('\r', '').replace('\t','').replace('\n','')
            url = response.urljoin(url)
            url = url.replace('details.asp','details_des.asp') + '&linked=&party_seq='
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.details)
```

Comment: If you post a _complete_ example instead it may be easier for someone to diagnose the problem.  See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

ok. the issue was with - `Messagepack is not available` ( this was in the Debug log, not in the errors though., and `page storage` enabled for this project.

I have disabled pagestorage and it works fine now.

I wished Error messages were more readable in Scrapy and SH.